# put command work with interactive "ftp", but not with "lftp"

Tags: linux, ftp, lftp

I want to send a file to an FTP server (which is out of my control), and when using the interactive Linux command `ftp`, this works fine:

```
[bf@localhost sudap]$ ftp ftp.example.net
Connected to ftp.example.net (1.1.1.1).
220 Serv-U FTP Server v15.3.0 ready...
Name (ftp.example.net:bf): USERNAME
331 User name okay, need password.
Password: ********
230 User logged in, proceed.
Remote system type is UNIX.
Using binary mode to transfer files.
ftp> put myfile.xlsx 
local: myfile.xlsx remote: myfile.xlsx
227 Entering Passive Mode (13,93,54,131,92,38)
150 Opening BINARY mode data connection for myfile.xlsx.
226 Transfer complete. 39,547 bytes transferred. 123.78 KB/sec.
39547 bytes sent in 0.139 secs (284.45 Kbytes/sec)
```

However, when I do the same with the `lftp` command (because I need this to run in a script), it fails to upload, with a bit of a cryptic message:

```
[bf@vps sudap]$ lftp
lftp :~> connect ftp://USERNAME:PASSWORD@ftp.example.net
lftp USERNAME@ftp.example.net:~> put myfile.xlsx
put: Access failed: 550 /: No such file. (myfile.xlsx)
```

How could I possibly fix this?

Answer (score 1):

Turns out (by using `debug 5`), that `lftp` issues an `ALLO` command, to which the server replies with the `550` error. `lftp` then aborts the transfer.

By using

```
set ftp:use-allo false
```

I fixed it.